# Changing the number format in google charts graphs

Tags: javascript, charts, number-formatting

I have a problem to change number format in my google chart.
I checked stackoverflow topic and I found it : http://jsfiddle.net/h5ea6xqu/
My problem is simple, I want exactly the same thing, but it doesn't working.

I have "," instead space for my grouping symbol... If someone have the solution, it would be awesome.
[my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGXkg.png)
My code :

```
   function drawChart($id) {
     var id=$id;
     var kwexist = (id + "_kw_exist");
     var kwexistvariable = $("#"+kwexist).html();

     var kwled = (id + "_kw_led");
     var kwledvariable = $("#"+kwled).html();

 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation' } ],
      ['Existant kWh', parseFloat(kwexistvariable), '#3B7CC9', parseFloat(kwexistvariable)],
      ['LED kWh', parseFloat(kwledvariable), '#3B7CC9' , parseFloat(kwledvariable)]
    ]);


    var options = {

    };

      var numberFormat = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
            groupingSymbol: ' '
        })

        numberFormat.format(data, 1);


    var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div_kw');
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chart_div);


    // Wait for the chart to finish drawing before calling the getImageURI() method.
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      chart_div.innerHTML = chart.getImageURI();
      var testokok = chart.getImageURI();
      console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
    });


    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Comment: Wow, I copy paste my code here : http://jsfiddle.net/4701Lbjm/ it's working on jsfiddle but in my application, here is the result : http://puu.sh/xstcv/efae425228.png
I have STRICTLY the same code... as you can see : http://puu.sh/xstdu/ca015d8f9b.png

Answer (score 0):

not sure i follow the question exactly

but if you want to format the number shown on the bar (annotation)

also format that column...

```
  numberFormat.format(data, 3);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart($id) {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation' } ],
    ['Existant kWh', parseFloat(10000), '#3B7CC9', parseFloat(10000)],
    ['LED kWh', parseFloat(15000), '#3B7CC9' , parseFloat(15000)]
  ]);

  var options = {

  };

  var numberFormat = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    groupingSymbol: ' '
  });
  numberFormat.format(data, 1);
  numberFormat.format(data, 3);

  var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chart_div);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Hello WhiteHat, thanks for you help, I found the solution.
Now I use "jsapi" instead of gstatic.com/charts/loader.js.

And now it's working perfectly with the same code...